# Is there a way to subset a group if ONLY the first observation meets a criteria?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, conditional-statements

I have a data frame like so:

```
ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
VAR_1 = c(2,4,6,1,7,9,4,4,3,1,7,4,0)
VAR_2 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,20190101,20190101,20190101,NA,20190101,NA,NA,NA)
df2 = data.frame(ID,VAR_1,VAR_2)
```

And I would like to subset from this data frame all the rows for every group (ID) **ONLY** if the first observation by group in VAR_2 has a value, In this simple case, the new subset should be all the rows from ID's 3 and 4

To represent this better:

```
df                                       df_subset   

ID VAR_1 VAR_2                           ID VAR_1 VAR_2
1   2     NA                             3   4     20190101                           
1   4     NA                             3   4     20190101
1   6     NA                             3   3     NA
2   1     NA                             4   1     20190101
2   7     NA                             4   7     NA
2   9     20190101                       4   4     NA
3   4     20190101                       4   0     NA
3   4     20190101
3   3     NA
4   1     20190101
4   7     NA
4   4     NA
4   0     NA
```

I manage to do this in several steps (I subset the original taking only the first observation by group,assign VAR_1 a special value, re-merge and then finally filter by the special value), but I would like to know if there's a simpler more elegant (and probably) more efficient way. I don't need VAR_1, so that can be changed if needed to provide a faster solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about df2[!is.na(df2$VAR_2),] which strips out all the NA values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, we can `group_by` `ID` and select groups only if first value in each group is non-NA.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(!is.na(VAR_2[1L]))

#     ID VAR_1    VAR_2
#  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     3     4 20190101
#2     3     4 20190101
#3     3     3       NA
#4     4     1 20190101
#5     4     7       NA
#6     4     4       NA
#7     4     0       NA
```

Some variations to extract first value could be (thanks to @tmfmnk)

```
df2 %>%  group_by(ID) %>% filter(!is.na(first(VAR_2)))
```

OR

```
df2 %>% group_by(ID) %>%  filter(!is.na(nth(VAR_2, 1)))
```

---

Same using base R `ave`

```
df2[with(df2, ave(!is.na(VAR_2), ID, FUN = function(x) x[1L])), ]
```

or a bit complicated one with `split` and `subset`

```
subset(df2, ID %in% names(na.omit(sapply(split(df2$VAR_2, df2$ID), head, 1))))
```

Comment: `df2 %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 filter(!is.na(first(VAR_2)))` could also work.